How to apply the correct theme color to a custom up indicator in the action bar?
How do I apply the correct color for the action bar in supportActionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator()?  I wind up getting the default icon tint color and not the action bar tint color when inflating and supplying a custom drawable.

The key is to use the correct theme when inflating the drawable.  If you use the theme from the action bar context, you will have the correct colors applied:
val actionBar = supportActionBar ?: throw IllegalStateException("Activity should have action bar.")
val closeDrawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.ic_close_white_24dp, actionBar.themedContext.theme)!!
ctionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(closeDrawable)

The key is using the theme actionBar.themedContext.theme, and not the default theme from the activity.
